# Как посмотреть метарепутацию?

Tags: поддержка, репутация, мета

Мета – сайт вспомогательный, поэтому репуация на нём не отображается – показывается цифра с основного сайта.

И всё же, насколько я слышал, репутация на метах считается. Точную ссылку не приведу, однако это очень похоже на правду и этому можно найти множество косвенных доказательств. Например, на мете свои отдельные медальки, для меток показывается рейтинг и т.п.:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот, есть ли какой-то способ посмотреть метарепутацию? Скажем, для одного конкретного человека или посмотреть список ТОП-пользователей какого-то метасайта?

Comment: На картинках не репутация, это рейтинг по меткам. Посмотреть можно по каждой метке отдельно. Общей мета-репутации нет.

Comment: @alexolut точно-точно нет или просто скрыта отовсюду?

Comment: @andreymal это только разрабы могут сказать. Но если что-то не торчит наружу, то можно считать, что этого нет концептуально.

Comment: Есть какая-никакая [аппроксимация на SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/rume/query/196452/top-users-rep-per-x-weeks).

Comment: @alexolut, да ладно? https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5vBj.png

Comment: @Qwertiy [прохладно](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/325798/3240681) :)